# tortoise svn link local files to repository after import

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created a repository by importing from a local copy of the project. To my surprise, after import finished, the local project was not linked to the repository.

How can I link the local project to the repository without having to checkout the entire project again? They are exactly the same because the repository was created from this local project.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Import does not convert your project files on disk to a working copy. You need to checkout the working copy in the same directory. Run the Checkout command into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Without performing a checkout, you can not.
Please read [this TortoiseSVN documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html).
Here is an extract:

> As soon as you press "OK" TortoiseSVN imports the complete directory
>   tree including all files into the repository. The project is now
>   stored in the repository under version control. **Please note that the
>   folder you imported is NOT under version control! To get a
>   version-controlled working copy you need to do a Checkout of the
>   version you just imported. Or read on to find out how to import a
>   folder in place.**

Reading further, it explains that you could also have first created a new empty project folder in the repository, checked it out, then perform `Add` actions. But it does not seem more efficient to me.